# Lowest dimension simple lie algebra representation of G2

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

Is there a simple way to prove that the smallest dimension of a simple lie algebra representation of G2 is 7?

I know that this can be computed using Weyl character formula, but I do not understand that formula very well, and I was wondering if a more direct approach was possible, especially if we are only interested with the smallest simple representation instead of all the simple representations.

Comment: How much highest weight theory would one be allowed to use? Also, how do you define the Lie algebra G2 to begin with (because if it's defined via matrices, there's some representation to begin with).

Comment: Just looking at the weight lattice and the Weyl group action on it will show you that aside from the trivial weight, every weight has an orbit of size at least 6 - therefore the dimension must be at least 6 by symmetry. A little more work (showing that if $V_\lambda \neq 0$ then $V_{\lambda - \alpha} \neq 0$ for all dominant $\lambda$ and positive roots $\alpha$) shows that there must be a nonzero trivial weight space, since the weight lattice of G2 coincides with the root lattice. So any nontrivial representaiton has weight at least 7.

Comment: Compare also with [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3067834/unique-faithful-7-dimensional-representation-of-semisimple-lie-algebra-with-g).